# Different set of files and flags for different builds

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU make for a project in Linux. I'd like to have a test and a prod build, and trying to implement it with conditional directives. Test build has different source files and flags etc. from the prod build.

First I found that *if* block only works when it's following a target.

```
# More variable definition skipped.

SRCS := some source files
CXXFLAGS := some complile flags

test: ${myBinary}
ifeq (${BUILD}, UNIT)
    @echo BUILD == ${BUILD}
  SRCS += ${TEST_SRCS}
  CXXFLAGS += some test flags
endif
```

I use this way so that later I can use a pattern to build .o files, instead of listing all source files for 2 different builds. Basically I try to find a way to use patterns to build .o files, yet still have different files, flags, etc. for test/prod builds.

```
${BUILD_DIR}/%.o : %.cpp
    ${CXX} -c ${CXXFLAGS} ${INCS} $< -o $@
```

But after I put it next to a target, still got this error:

```
make: SRCS: Command not found
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

How to fix it to meet my goal?

Other advice on organizing the makefile to meet the goal is most welcomed too.

**Edit:**

- The 2 executables produced can have different names but can be in same location.
- I wanna put object files are in ${BUILD_DIR} to separate them from source files.
- "Command not found" error is gone after unindenting SRCS line.

Comment: You're trying to solve two problems at once, and you've given us so little information about what you're trying to do that any solution we suggest probably wouldn't be what you want. Do you want `test` and `prod` to produce executables with different names? Do you want them to put the executables in different places? What about the object files?

Comment: `SRCS: Command not found` is an error from the shell. You have indented `SRCS += ${TEST_SRCS}` with a tab, so that _make_ thinks it's a command-line to be passed to the shell when you ask it to build `test`.